# 'newwcf.Client' does not contain a definition for 'Where'

Tags: asp.net, wcf

```
hi i have the following code:
```

but i m getting an error 
    'newwcf.Client' does not contain a definition for 'Where'
    please help..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace newwcf
{
    public class myservice : Imyservice 
    {
      public  List<ClientDetails> getClient()
        {
            List<ClientDetails> client = new List<ClientDetails>();
            var sql = Client.Where(cn => cn.ClientName).ToList();  //getting the error here
            return sql;

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

c# is case sensitive...should you try

`var sql = client.Where(cn => cn.ClientName).ToList();`

Comment: do you have a Client class? the client variable refers to the List<ClientDetails> so there should be a .Where method.

Comment: yup i do have a client class